# Solve $\cos(2x)>|\sin(x)|$ for $x\in [-\pi/2,\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

My approach:
$\cos(2x)>\sin(x) $   or $ \cos(2x)<-\sin(x)$

First case
After solving gives (2\sin(x)-1)(\sin(x)+1)<0
Solving this i get that
x belongs to $(-\pi/2 , \pi/6) \cup(5\pi/6 , \pi)$

Solving other case i get
$(2\sin x+1)(\sin x-1)>0$
x belongs to $(-\pi/6 , 0)$

But the answer to the question is
$(-\pi/6 , \pi/6) \cup (5\pi/6 , \pi)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For $-\dfrac\pi2<x\le0\  \ \ \  (1)$

$$\cos2x>-\sin x\iff0<1-2\sin^2x+\sin x$$

$$\iff0>2\sin^2x-\sin x-1=(2\sin x+1)(\sin x-1)$$

Now in $-\dfrac\pi2<x\le0,\sin x-1<0$

So, we need $2\sin x+1>0\iff\sin x>-\dfrac12=\sin\left(-\dfrac\pi6\right)$

$\implies x>-\dfrac\pi6\  \  \ \ (2)$

Take the intersection of $(1),(2)$

Set $x=-y$ to find the case of $\dfrac\pi2>x\ge0\  \  \ \ (2)$

For the third case, $\dfrac\pi2<x<\pi,$

$$\cos2x>\sin x$$

Can you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As for real $a, |a|^2=a^2$

So, $$\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x=1-2|\sin x|^2$$

So, we need $$0<1-2|\sin x|^2+|\sin x|\iff0>2|\sin x|^2-|\sin x|-1=(2|\sin x|-1)(|\sin x|+1)$$

As $|\sin x|\ge0,|\sin x|+1\ge1>0$

So, we need $2|\sin x|-1<0\iff|\sin x|<\dfrac12=\sin\dfrac\pi6$

For $-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le\dfrac\pi2,-\dfrac\pi6<x<\dfrac\pi6\ \  \ \ (1)$

Now if $y$ is a solution of $(1),$ so will be $\pi-y$

$\implies-\dfrac\pi6<\pi-x<\dfrac\pi6\iff ?<x<?$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos 2x-|\sin x|>0$$
$$1-2\sin^2x-|\sin x|>0$$

Let $\sin x=y$

$$1-2y^2-|y|>0$$
$$2y^2+|y|-1>0$$

when $y>0$, 
$$2y^2+y-1>0$$
$$(y+1).(y-0.5)>0$$
$$\sin x>1/2$$

and when $y<0$
$$2y^2-y-1>0$$
$$(y-1)(y+0.5)>0$$
$$\sin x<1/2$$

I guess this much hint is enough?